# Angularjs Directive initialized in different order in IE11 and FireFox31

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive where I define a link function in which I added few login listeners(custom).

And the respective broadcast will happen from a factory based on a condition. which is the function in my controller. But when I execute the application the $rootscope does not get the listeners init.

My code is something like follows,

**Directive :**

```
.directive("tetsdirective",function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: true, 
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: "../xx.htm"
    link: function(scope) {

      $rootScope.$on('loginSuccess', function () {
      alert('login success');}
    }
  }
}
```

**Factory :**

```
.factory('login',function() {
  return {
    listen : function() {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('loginSuccess');
    }
  }
})
```

**Controller :**

```
function applicationCtrl(login) {
  login.listen();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="applicationCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <tetsdirective></tetsdirective>
  </div>
</body>
```

Dependency is added in the controller for directive and also for service/factory. This works well from IE11. ie, at the time of doing the broadcast , if we check the $rootscope listeners, the listner is added and the it will give me the alert as well.

but when I try it from Firefox -v31, the listener is not added at the time of broadcast, and when debugged, the initialization of the directive happens only after the broadcast.

I was wondering why both the browsers behave differently. Am I doing something wrong here?

Please note : All the required dependencies are injected including $Rootscope. There is no error shown in IE/FF

Comment: Don't know if its a typo, but you're not injecting $rootScope in either directive of factory. But that would generate a different error.

Comment: Sorry...I just edited.All the required dependencies are injected. There is no error shown

Comment: Could you show the html where the `tetsdirective` and `applicationCtrl` are used?

Comment: I'm wondering how could it work in IE11. The `applicationCtrl` should be instantiated before its children directive get compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue , this is not working due to the order of execution.

When the controller initiates the service to do the broadcast, the link function might not have registered the listener to the $root.

Here only option I could see is to register the listener from the directive itself instead of doing from the link function.

```
.directive("tetsdirective",function() {
   $rootScope.$on('loginSuccess', function () 
            {
               alert('login success');
             }
 return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: true, 
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: "../xx.htm"

       }
}
```